# Does the golang AWS SDK automatically compute and check a checksum for an object when using the upload manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I'm having a hard time determining a definitive answer to this question from the AWS docs.  I've read mixed things.  I see on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html): "Amazon S3 uses checksum values to verify the integrity of data that you upload to or download from Amazon S3. In addition, you can request that another checksum value be calculated for any object that you store in Amazon S3." - this seems to suggest that by default S3 is computing a checksum and the SDK is comparing against it when uploading or downloading objects, and that in addition a separate and additional checksum algorithm may be used. This is maybe the MD5 checksum that is stored in the ETag?

There is also [this page on the S3 CLI application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-faq.html#upload) which aligns with the above idea, but not sure if the same goes for the SDK.

Does anyone know if my understand of this is correct?  Or does the user need to specify one of [SHA-1, SHA-256, CRC32, CRC32C] when using upload manager, and request that the checksum be verified when uploading?